# Influxdb 2.x how to get the last field per tag value?

Tags: database, influxdb, influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

I'm using this query to fetch all the available tag values from the measurement:

```
schema.measurementTagValues(
    bucket: "XYZ",
    measurement: "ABC",
    tag: "test",
)
```

This results in me all the tagValue in measurement ABC.

How can I use these tagValue to fetch the last field per tag from the same or a different measurement?

Here is what I tried:

```
import "influxdata/influxdb/schema"
 
data = schema.measurementTagValues(
    bucket: "XYZ",
    measurement: "ABC",
    tag: "test",
)

from(bucket: "XYZ")
|> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] ==  "ABC" or r["test"] == data) 
|> last()
```

This throws `unsupported binary expression string == stream` error.

Any other ways to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the last record for each tag key?

If so, you could try with either InfluxQL:

```
SELECT LAST(*) FROM ABS GROUP BY "test"
```

or Flux:

```
from(bucket: "XYZ")
|> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] ==  "ABC"
|> group(columns: ["test"], mode: "by")
|> last()
```

Comment: Not working for me. It's throwing an error "schema collision: cannot group float and string types together". Not sure why. And also, I'm trying to avoid passing a range as I need the last field from all available tags, or else I'll have to give a very large range( with a slow response time).

Comment: "schema collision: cannot group float and string types together" implies that your tag has mixed types of values? Maybe this is something you can look into.